# iOS - One Vector Image for All iPhone Resolutions

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcasset

I am trying to create one vector image for all screen sizes of iPhones. I created pdf file using Illustrator with size for iPhone 6 plus i.e. 1242*231 (231 is my required height of image) and Included it in image assets and changed scaling factor to Single Vector.

Now it is being displayed in **iPhone 6 plus** with no problem. But when i try the same Single Vector Image in iPhone 6 it is squeezed.

I found out on web that pdf image is converted to @2x and 1@x automatically. like if i have 300*300@3x it is converted to 200*200 and 100*100.

According to this then it is the right behavior because 1242/2 = 621 and it required 750 to display accurately.

But my question is that wasn't the vector image suppose to adjust it? Any other work around this problem?

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. If the image is, as you say, "squeezed", i.e. the aspect ratio is broken, then the issue is probably not the assets but rather some constraints. Or do you mean that the image is not scaled to the correct resolution? Maybe you could provide a screen shot of the problem.

Comment: Also mind that when working with pdf vector assets you should make it the size in *points* you want (or, in pixels, the same as @1x)

Answer (score 1):

Try to save it in svg format, this would be better solution.